# Docker container stops immediately after using docker start

Tags: .net, docker

I'm facing an issue when trying to use Docker to run a .NET Core application, the issue is that when I try to run the container using

`docker run --name ticket-management-api tickets/ticket-management-api -p 81:80`

It only shows this message: (I undestand that this message is from the logs of the container)

```
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.10 initialized 'TicketsContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.10' with options: MigrationsHistoryTable=_MigrationHistory
[04:02:09 INF] Entity Framework Core 6.0.10 initialized 'TicketsContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.10' with options: MigrationsHistoryTable=_MigrationHistory
```

and right after this, the container stops, no error in log files, no information about whatever happened to the container, it just stops. (I know that it has stopped because when I run `docker ps -a` the container has "Exited" status and has no port).

I tried to run the application locally in my computer and it works without any issue.

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Security.Api/Security.Api.csproj", "Security.Api/"]
COPY ["Security.Domain/Security.Domain.csproj", "Security.Domain/"]
COPY ["Security.Infrastructure/Security.Infrastructure.csproj", "Security.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Security.Application/Security.Application.csproj", "Security.Application/"]

RUN dotnet restore "Security.Api/Security.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Security.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Security.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Security.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Security.Api.dll"]
```

I followed the docs in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/docker-application-development-process/docker-app-development-workflow to create the Dockerfile

I hope you can help me about information of how can I troubleshoot this or any idea of how may I.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is your `Security.Api.csproj` project? Isn't the `Security.Application.csproj` the application project?

Comment: Api is the project that has the Program.cs file, Application project is more likely the bussiness project.